# NSUserDefaults and sandboxing under Lion

Tags: objective-c, plist, osx-lion, nsuserdefaults, sandbox

Moving one of my projects to support sandboxing as per Apple's requirements. I use UserDefaults like so:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@(myNumber) forKey:myNumberKey];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

Everything works as expected until I enable sandboxing. If I have sandboxing enabled the app creates a lock file in it's sandbox directory ( .plist.lockfile) and doesn't create an actual .plist file.

What am I doing wrong and how do I store my settings in UserDefaults under sandbox environment?

Update: Installed fresh 10.7.3 with the latest Xcode on a separate Mac - the same project compiles and works fine with sandboxing enabled.

Also I've tried to run this project on my Mac where the sandbox doesn't work under different user account (freshly created) with exactly the same results - no go. At this point I think the problem is with system configuration on this particular mac. Question is though - is it safe to assume that I'm the only one with this weird problem? Probably not...

Comment: I also have sandbox enabled but the user defaults work great. I am not sure what the synchronize method is good for, but I am also using  `[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] registerDefaults:defaultValues];` when I initialize my user defaults.

Answer (score 2):

That should work fine. If the preferences system is able to create the lock file, that means your app has appropriate privileges to create files in that directory and has correctly looked up the location where it should put them. Therefore, something else must be going wrong.

Is there any Console logging when this occurs? What's the return value of -synchronize?

(aside: in general -synchronize is not necessary and will just make your app slower, NSUserDefaults will handle that itself)

Comment: -synchronize is only needed if you plan on using the data before the system has a chance to fully store the values. It is basically a forced save event for the default values. Otherwise the OS will save things when it gets around to it.

Comment: Not quite true. It's needed if you expect *another process* to use the data in that time period. If you're only accessing it in one process (in 99% of apps, that's the case), then it's available immediately.

Comment: -synchronize returns 0 (write fails)

Comment: Would it be possible to get a copy of an app (either your app or a reduced version of it) to try debugging it myself? This *should* work.

Comment: sure. here is a sample project which doesn't work for me:
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/51668664/NSDefaultsTest.zip
 Furthermore - I've tried a few Apple examples with exactly the same result - settings do not save in sandbox. I did a "file activity" trace on the above project and I get -1 file descriptor on my plist file (it can't open the file). But it doesn't create the file in a first place... I've contacted Apple's dev support but so far they can't figure it out...

Comment: I'll take a look once I dig myself out of the hole I'm in with my own project :) Thanks!

Comment: Need to get things set up to build it sandboxed; I'm all configured for framework development, which has sorta different needs.