# Best practices for updating files in OS X App Sandbox

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, sandbox, appstore-sandbox

I'm aware of the methods for migrating a non-sandboxed app to an app sandbox, although I would like to know what the best practices would be for updating files (mostly preference lists) once already in an app sandbox container?

Ultimately if there's a method similar to `NSUserDefaults` that would work for updating my preference list in an app sandbox container that's what I'm looking to do.

Sources I've read:

• [App Sandbox Design Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Security/Conceptual/AppSandboxDesignGuide/MigratingALegacyApp/MigratingAnAppToASandbox.html)

• [NSUserDefaults Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

• [App Sandboxing](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/mac/app-sandbox/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're actually storing preferences, just use NSUserDefaults. It works the same (from an API perspective) inside a sandbox as outside. It's really best to pretend that preferences aren't stored in plists though; relying on that implementation detail can have all sorts of unfortunate side effects on recent OSs, so just use the API.

If you're trying to modify arbitrary plists rather than storing preferences, *don't* use NSUserDefaults. Use NSPropertyListSerialization and read/write them directly.

Comment: *I'm curious about the side effects you've mentioned; also nice answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9268899/1125006). :)

Comment: Heh, I have that question open in the tab next to this one to remind me to respond to the last comment on my answer. The side effects I mention are that in Mountain Lion, the "truth" of preferences is stored in a daemon, not on disk (the disk is still used to persist them though). Deleting/replacing the file may or may not be reflected in the API immediately, and if you're really unlucky, it may be overwritten by an asynchronous write from the daemon. Similarly, reading directly may not get the most up to date data.